# loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization:

Tags: java, axis, webservice-client, jboss6.x

When i deploy a web service project in jboss 6 .I am getting the below stackrace

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.getChildElements(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Ljava/util/Iterator;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/axis/message/MessageElement, and the class loader (instance of ) for interface javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotatedClassFilter.hasAnnotations(AnnotatedClassFilter.java:186) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotatedClassFilter.accepts(AnnotatedClassFilter.java:114) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotatedClassFilter.visit(AnnotatedClassFilter.java:99) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:407) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:395) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.getClasses(WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:172) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processMetaData(WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:145) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:119) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(WarAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:80) [:6.0.0.20100429-M3]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.Alpha4]
    ... 26 more

Please help me ..... :)

Comment: check the versions of jb/jdk and axis if they are compatible with each other

Comment: The issue got fixed .... :)

Note: This was due to conflict between the jar in the jboss and jar in my class path ....

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because in your web application at least exists a jar which contains the `javax.xml.namespace.QName` class and that class conflicts with the same one contained in one of the JBoss's jar.

You should remove that (these) jar(s) from your web application when deploying on JBoss.

A list of jars which contain the `javax.xml.namespace.QName` class is at http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html

Answer (score 0):

We encounter this issue if EAR/WAR file is created using eclipse

It is a clear case of having two jar files in the EAR/war file.

Open EAR/WAR fileusing WinRAR and check whether two axis.jar file is present. If yes then delete and the jar file and redeploy